# How do I convert from a cli::array<unsigned char> to a String?

Tags: .net, arrays, c++-cli

I have a `array<unsigned char>^` which contains a load of ascii characters which I'd like to convert into a `String^`. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/f94ca9d3-17ba-4fc1-9c4b-be94f0b77f06):

```
BufferedStream file = gcnew BufferedStream(gcnew FileStream(fileName,FileMode::Open)); 
array<unsigned char>^ arr = gcnew array<unsigned char>(10); 
file->Read(arr,0,10); 

String^ s; 
Text::Encoding^ enc = Text::Encoding::UTF8; 
s = enc->GetString(arr);
```

Comment: You said they were ASCII characters in the array. Wouldn't Text::Encoding::ASCII be more appropriate?

Comment: Both appear to work for the data sets I'm using but ASCII probably _is_ more appropriate. My code actually uses ASCII but the example I was quoting says UTF8...